# AwesomeWM: for iterator is not callable (a table value) when iterating on clients

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I'm trying to toggle all the titlebars when I press some keys. For this I want to iterate over all clients. I tries to do it several ways, including:

```
for s in screen do
 for c in s.clients do
  awful.titlebar.toggle(c)
 end
end
```

and

```
for c in client.get() do
 awful.titlebar.toggle(c)
end
```

Every time this code it executed I get an error: `for iterator 'for iterator' is not callable (a table value)`.

This makes no sense to me. Can you explain why this happens and how to solve my problem?

I am running Awesome 4.3 with Lua 5.4.3.

Also, if you have an elegant way of toggling the titlebars that also impacts new clients, I'm taking. Thanks.

edit: I'd like to precise that the error occurs even without `awful.titlebar.toggle(c)` in the for-loops

Comment: `s.clients` is not callable.  You should place a function here.  Or an expression which returns a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Piglet answer is correct, but here's the actual "how to fix it":

```lua
for index, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
    awful.titlebar.toggle(c)
end
```

The problem/confusion here is mostly historical. Someone made the `screen` into a loop iterator because they were thinking it was a cool time saver.

However, it is the only object in the whole API which work that way (and there wont be more). Other object use `module_name()` as a constructor, not a loop iterator. This is unfixable without breaking the API, so it persist. We cannot break APIs we document because it would break people configs when they upgrade.

Every other table/list in the AwesomeWM API requires either `ipairs()` or `pairs()` to iterate. `ipairs` is for ordered list/tables while `pairs` is for dictionaries.

Comment: "because they were thinking it was a cool time saver." Either that or it was back when I was trying to get rid of screen indicies because an index can change when screens are added/removed. :-P Oh and you can always just add `screen.get()` doing nothing (just returning `screen`) (or returning some table with screens) just for symmetry with `client.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

the loops you're using are generic for loops. they expect a list of expressions after the keyword in. The first one must be an iterator function.

In your code this is missing. Instead there is a non callable table.

From the [Lua Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5):

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>  for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do body end works as follows.
> ```
>
> The names var_i declare loop variables local to the loop body. The
> first of these variables is the control variable.
>
> The loop starts by evaluating explist to produce four values: an
> iterator function, a state, an initial value for the control variable,
> and a closing value.

I don't know your variables `screen`, `s.clients` and the return value of `client.get` but as the error is complaining about a table value you probably just forgot to call `pairs` with that table as argument.

> This makes no sense to me.

Because you don't know the very basics of Lua. Read the manual. How can you expect to use something complex as a generic for loop properly without referring to the manual?